# Microsoft Face API error in method identify()

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using project oxford for Microsoft Face API in JavaScript, when I use the function "identify", I receive "Invalid request body."

```
                    client.face.identify({
                       faces: arrayFaceId,
                       personGroupId: "groupId",
                       maxNumOfCandidatesReturned: 1,
                       confidenceThreshold: 0.8
                    }).then(function(response){
                       console.log('Response ' + JSON.stringify(response.personId));
                    }, function(error){
                     console.log("Error2"+JSON.stringify(error));
                   });
```

Anyone knows how I could fix it?

Comment: Can you include links to documentation at Question?

Comment: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/project-oxford#Client.face..detect

Comment: Can you include `arrayFaceId` at Question?

Comment: var arrayFaceId = ["57d1d0d0-09b6-46ea-a4d2-e173eae733c4"];

Comment: @blex Curious where you located that instruction at documentation?

Comment: changing it to faceIds didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API in question takes regular arguments, not an object as you've specified.  So:

```
client.face.identify(arrayFaceId, "groupId", 1, 0.8)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('Response ' + JSON.stringify(response.personId));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```